Not wanting to rely on Bittul
I seem to remember one of the Poskim on Yoreh Deah (Shach?) saying that if one does not want to rely on Bittul to eat something into which issur fell (and was annulled via bittul) then he is akin to a kofer. Can someone help me locate the source for this?

https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.116.10
